# Is it possible to pass a function with id parameter from a child component to the parent component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, react-props

Is it possible to pass a function with id parameter  from a child component to the parent component with React?
I'm trying to pass the function as a prop to it's parent component.
The scheme of the components is the App component -> TasksList component -> Task Component. So I need by clicking on a specific task to route to this task, using its individual Id.
The point is that after routing to the task after clicking the url changes to /task/009, but the Task component isn't rendered.

https://codesandbox.io/s/test-login-page-tasks-rmfn5j?file=/src/components/Taskslist.js

```js
//App component
const Tasks = [
  {
    id: "001",
    status: 0,
    priority: 2,
    title: "Develop website homepage",
    description:
      "Create a visually appealing and responsive homepage for the website",
    schedule: {
      creation_time: "2021-07-23T10:00:00"
    },
    author_name: "John Smith"
  },
  {
    id: "002",
    status: 1,
    priority: 1,
    title: "Implement user authentication",
    description: "Add user authentication feature to the website",
    schedule: {
      creation_time: "2021-07-24T14:30:00"
    },
    author_name: "Sarah Lee"
  }
  ]
  
  function App() {
  const [tasks, setTasks] = useState(Tasks);
  return (
  
    <Route path="/taskslist">
      <Taskslist Tasks={tasks} />
    </Route>
  )

// Parent component
import React from "react";

const Taskslist = ({ Tasks }) => {
  const history = useHistory();

  const goToTask = (taskId) => {
    history.push(`/task/${taskId}`);
  };

  return (
    <Task
      Tasks={Tasks.filter((task) => task.status === 0)}
      goToTask={goToTask}
    />
}

//Child component

import React from "react";

const Task = ({ Tasks, goToTask }) => {
  return (
    <div className="wrapper">
      {Tasks.map((task) => (
        <div key={task.id} onClick={goToTask(task.id)}>
          <h3>{task.title}</h3>
        </div>
      ))}
    </div>
  );
};

export default Task;
```

Answer (score 0):

Multiple Issues

1. `<div key={task.id} onClick={goToTask(task.id)}>`
   This line is where I was able to see the first issue.
   You are calling the goToTask Immediately.
2. In your App component, you are not rendering the Task component for the individual task routes. To fix this, you can define a route for the individual task in your App component and render the Task component for that route, like this:

```js
function App() {
  const [tasks, setTasks] = useState(Tasks);

  return (
    <Router>
      <Switch>
        <Route path="/taskslist">
          <Taskslist Tasks={tasks} />
        </Route>
        <Route path="/task/:id">
          <Task Tasks={tasks} />
        </Route>
      </Switch>
    </Router>
  );
}
```

3. In your `Task` component you need to makes sure that you filter your selected task from the URL. use the `useParams()`

```
import { useParams } from "react-router";

const Task = ({ Tasks }) => {
  const { id } = useParams();
  const task = Tasks.find((task) => task.id === id);

  return (
    <div>
      <h3>{task.title}</h3>
      <p>{task.description}</p>
      {/* ... */}
    </div>
  );
};
```

lemme know if further help is required.